# Git ignored file is being tracked even after git rm and git checkout

Tags: git, version-control, gitx

Git is an awesome beast of an SCM. Yet I am endlessly perplexed by an issue.

I have a config file which are in the `.gitignore` and not in the `master` branch on `origin` (via `git show -- config/mongo.yml`). However on my branch, which was checked out from `origin/master` and worked on for a while, the file is being tracked somehow and when I `git rm` and `git checkout` out from `origin/master` again, the files stay in my repo but disappear for everyone else on my team. I ran `git rm --cached` as well, and as a last resort I ran:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- config/mongo.yml
```

Which I have used many times to good effect on ignored files, and the branch was small enough to redo. However, this doesn't seem to be the fix. I really would just like to know the "why" of this and understand the problem, since that is 3/4 of the solution!! :)

How could I have it in my `.gitignore` and then it shows up tracked after `git rm config/mongo.yml` and `git checkout origin/master -- config/mongo.yml`?

Comment: Not sure about the exact answer, but I think there might be a branch conflict, where one branch is tracking the file and another branch isn't tracking the file. What do you get when you do **git status**

Comment: # Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# new file:   config/mongo.yml

Comment: but since git rm and git rm --cached should completely remove the file from being tracked, this should not happen in my understanding.

Comment: what command are you using to commit? are you doing this by any chance? `git commit -am "blah blah"`

Comment: No. Seperate adding and commiting phases.

Comment: what's in your .gitignore file?

Comment: I don't think `ruby`, `ruby-on-rails`, or `gitx` are relevant tags for this question.

Comment: thanks. will remember for future.

Comment: If it's worth anything the reset I tend to use in situations like this is `git reset --hard HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

Things I've tried when something's odd:

*removing* that file from .gitignore and switching to a commit that doesn't have that file (and doesn't have it in .gitignore).

`git ls-files --cached --ignored --exclude-standard` in every checkout whose behavior I'm having trouble explaining.  I do it every so often anyway.

`git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph path/to/your/cuckoo`, that shows everywhere that file's status or contents changed. You can get gitk to do the same thing, bring up a new View.

Also, try cloning to a neighbor directory, it'll hardlink everything but the checked-out content so space isn't a factor.  That'll get you a pristine worktree without losing state in your current one, you can experiment there and `git clean -dfx` to clean up any messes casually.